# Как заменить данные в строке регуляркой с данными из переменной?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти текст и обернуть его в теги с классом. Например ищу текст "при". Если я просто пишу через паттерн, то всё хорошо:

```js
let str = 'Принадлежности и приложение';
let result = str.replace(/(при)/ig, '<span class="wrap">$1</span>');
console.log(result);
```

Однако текст динамический, его вводит пользователь. Я вынес данные в переменную и пытаюсь использовать `RegExp`

```js
let str = 'Принадлежности и приложение';
let searchValue = 'при';
let pattern = new RegExp(searchValue, 'gi');
let result =str.replace(pattern, '<span class="wrap">$1</span>');
console.log(result);
```

Но в итоге ничего не подставляется. Что нужно изменить в коде, чтоб значение заменялось как в первом примере?

Пока получилось как-то так:

```
result = str.replace(pattern, '<span class="wrap">' + pattern.exec(str)[0] + '</span>');
```

Не знаю это верно или можно как-то по-другому

Comment: Выражения разные: во втором случае ты забыл скобочки группы. Фикс: `const searchValue = '(при)';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы просто забыли скобки, которые нужны для использования `$1` в замене. Попробуйте так:

```js
let pattern = new RegExp(`(${searchValue})`, 'gi');
```

Comment: Спасибо!. Пытался скобки в RegExp добавить но не получалось. Надо было их как строку сделать. Теперь всё ясно.

Comment: кто-то нам минусы поставил

Comment: @helloworld Может, кто-то подумал, что такой короткий ответ можно было сделать комментарием/ Но я посчитал, что случай достаточно значимый, чтобы оформить ответом.

Comment: Минус (не мой) вероятно за то что ситуация из категории "не воспроизводится" - то есть, он не для осуждения ответа, а для того чтобы ответ не помешал автоудалению вопроса как мусорного, бесполезного сообществу (и как раз по этой причине, от плюсиков и принятия тут лучше воздержаться - чего не все понимают, к сожалению). То есть, это норм что вопрос задан, но в базе знаний он принесет пользы, т.к. эта проблема по сути от невнимательности (нетехническая).

Comment: @yar85 Ну, мне показалось, что тут больше чем опечатка, тут хороший случай разобраться, как создаются динамические регулярки. Но я могу ошибаться, конечно)

Comment: Так ТС вполне правильно и успешно создает регулярку, с этим у него проблем не возникло. Проблема появилась только от того что выражение было переписано (скопировано/перенесено) с ошибкой: из-за пропущенных по невнимательности скобочек оно перестало соответствовать желаемому алгоритму. Почему кейс расценивается как невнимательность - потому что ну не может человек, желающий получить первую группу результата `$1`, _сознательно_ убрать эту группу из выражения :)

Comment: @yar85 я не совсем разбираюсь в регуоярках) и решения также смотрел на всяких SO. Так вот когда я изначально пытался вставить переменную в `.replace(/searchValue/g, '<span>$1</span>')` ничего не выходило. на enSO нашёл, что надо использовать `let reg = new RegExp(searchValue, 'i')` https://stackoverflow.com/q/10136097/6104996 . Я переписал. Получилось то, что в вопросе. Так что не совсем опечатка)

Comment: @helloworld, главное же не определить "опечатка/неопечатка". Тут в комментах речь **о характере проблемы**, которая в свою очередь определяет формулировку вопроса и его **полезность**. В отношении вопросов, полезность это по сути находимость: те которые заданы о типичных/повторяемых проблемах - полезны, как раз потому что ситуации повторяемые - ответ и решение легко найти поиском. Тут не содержится повторяемой технической проблемы, вот в чем соль: найти этот ответ можно только осознавая "я забыл скобки" - но при таком осознании ничего искать уже не нужно, т.к. решение становится очевидным.

Comment: @yar85 для меня лично было не очевидно. потому что в решении enSO было написано просто добавь переменную в конструктор regexp. Ну не важно. Спасибо **vsemozhebuty** за ответ

Comment: @helloworld, то что ответ принес пользу лично тебе - это понятно. Но, еще раз: речь в комментариях не о тебе, и не об этом ответе - речь о **полезности _вопроса_** для сообщества. Я считаю что именно она повлияла на оценку ответа, а вовсе не содержимое ответа или твое удовлетворение этим содержимым.